# Powershell get unniqe based on column

Tags: powershell

I have the following Data File:

```
1/1/2021 08:57:16 a.b 990    0
1/1/2021 20:17:16 a.b 990    1
1/2/2021 10:17:16 a.b 990    0
1/2/2021 20:17:16 a.b 990    1
1/3/2021 08:44:16 a.b 990    0
1/3/2021 18:30:16 a.b 990    1
```

Im trying to find a way to sort it so dates would not appear more than once.
if i use Get-Unique i dont get the result i want,
i can manipulate it to cut only the dates and then maybe use Get-Unique but im sure there's a better way

The end result should be

```
1/1/2021 08:57:16 a.b 990    0
1/2/2021 10:17:16 a.b 990    0
1/3/2021 18:30:16 a.b 990    0
```

Comment: You could use `Group-Object` first and then a `Get-Unique` or `Sort-Object -Unique` or `Select-Object -Unique`

Comment: `Get-Content path\to\file |Sort-Object {$_.Split()[0]} -Unique`

Comment: Please consider clarifying if the data file is structured or plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a plain text data file...

```
"1/1/2021 08:57:16 a.b 990    0
1/1/2021 20:17:16 a.b 990    1
1/2/2021 10:17:16 a.b 990    0
1/2/2021 20:17:16 a.b 990    1
1/3/2021 08:44:16 a.b 990    0
1/3/2021 18:30:16 a.b 990    1" > data.txt
```

Using CSV import would make it easy for you to get the result wanted

```
Get-Content .\data.txt | 
  ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ' ' -Header Date,Time,Data,Number,nul1,nul2,nul3,Iteration | 
  Select Date, Time, Data, Number, Iteration | # Filter out unused "data columns"
  Sort -Unique Date | ft # Strip out duplicate dates (and present in a table)
```

or another way of stripping nulX

```
Get-Content .\data.txt |
   ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ' ' -Header Date,Time,Data,Number,nul1,nul2,nul3,Iteration |
   Select * -ExcludeProperty nul1,nul2,nul3 | 
   Sort -Unique Date | ft
```